# Batch loading in DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

Hi Currently I am loading each row row in Dynamodb which is veryslow.
I have a huge data which i want to load to DynamoDb by JAVA API.
But this takes huge time .For example to load 1 million data it took me 2 days to load to Dynamo.

Is Batch load possible in DynamoDb.I am not finding any information about bulkload or batch load.

Appreciate any help here.

Comment: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_BatchWriteItem.html  to batch write the items.

Comment: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_BatchGetItem.html   to batch read the items

Answer (score -1):

i know it's an old post, but we came up short exploring how to optimize this so embarked on a scientific discovery :)

http://tech.equinox.com/driving-miss-dynamodb/

long and short of it it Hive on EMR is an excellent option (i know, it's "old skool").. 
using and tuning these parameters do the trick (see blog for details):

```
SET dynamodb.throughput.write.percent = x;
SET mapred.reduce.tasks = x;
SET hive.exec.reducers.bytes.per.reducer = x;
SET tez.grouping.split-count = x;
```

Comment: link is not found and the question was about how to do a batch request